Why does my producer-consumer program using pthread_cond_signal get stuck?
I am writing a producer-consumer program using pthread in C. The program should produce and consume items up to a limit n. However, my program usually gets stuck quickly when n = 1 and n = 2.
To be more specific, "get stuck" means it stop printing any "(" or ")". The programm need to exit mannually.
@mch @Ted Thanks for your helpful reminders.I used Godbolt to demonstrate a minimal reproducible example of the bug and identified that the visually noticeable bug appears when n=1 or n=2. It seems to run correctly when n=3 or more.
An example in godbolt is given，where the stdout is expected to be longer. Set the arg input to 1 and 2 get an error, set to 3 or more works fine.
https://godbolt.org/z/dKens4z4f
Here is my code.
#include "thread.h"
#include <semaphore.h>

int n, count = 0;

pthread_mutex_t lk = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void Tproduce(){
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&lk);
                while(count == n){
                        pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lk);
                }
                assert(count != n);
                printf("(");
                count++;
                //printf("%d\t", count);
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lk);
        }
}


void Tconsume(){
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&lk);
                while(count == 0){
                        pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lk);
                }
                assert(count != 0);
                printf(")");
                count--;
                //printf("%d\t",count);
                pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lk);
        }
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        assert(argc==2);
        n=atoi(argv[1]);
        setbuf(stdout,NULL);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                create(Tproduce);
                create(Tconsume);
        }
}

create here is simply create a thread in a self-made thread pool, which is tested working fine.
I tried using pthread_cond_broadcast or using two condition variables, and both approaches work fine. However, I cannot figure out why the program gets stuck when using pthread_cond_signal.
There should be at least one thread that works correctly, and all blocked threads should have a chance to be awakened. Even if a producer thread or consumer thread is incorrectly awakened and tries to acquire the lock, they should compete with threads that have never acquired the futex lock before. Since these incorrectly awakened threads do not satisfy the condition, they will release the lock, allowing the outside threads (those that never acquired the futex lock) to acquire it.
Therefore, in the worst-case scenario, taking the producer as an example, whether the consumer thread is blocked on the futex lock or on the condition variable, it should always have a chance to be called and should not get completely stuck.
I am running this code in WSL2,ubuntu 20, if it helps.
I will be very grateful for any ideas or solutions.
Add:
The thread.h header file provides a simple thread pool implementation using POSIX threads (pthread). It defines a maximum of 64 threads and includes basic functionality for creating and joining threads.
It runs under gcc 9.4.0.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NTHREAD 64
enum { T_FREE = 0, T_LIVE, T_DEAD, };
struct thread {
  int id, status;
  pthread_t thread;
  void (*entry)(int);
};

struct thread tpool[NTHREAD], *tptr = tpool;

void *wrapper(void *arg) {
  struct thread *thread = (struct thread *)arg;
  thread->entry(thread->id);
  return NULL;
}

void create(void *fn) {
  assert(tptr - tpool < NTHREAD);
  *tptr = (struct thread) {
    .id = tptr - tpool + 1,
    .status = T_LIVE,
    .entry = fn,
  };
  pthread_create(&(tptr->thread), NULL, wrapper, tptr);
  ++tptr;
}

void join() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NTHREAD; i++) {
    struct thread *t = &tpool[i];
    if (t->status == T_LIVE) {
      pthread_join(t->thread, NULL);
      t->status = T_DEAD;
    }
  }
}

__attribute__((destructor)) void cleanup() {
  join();
}


You should show us the create function. Currently, after the 16 create calls, main ends and terminates the program.

It's never a good idea to have printf statements without a \n.  Such is case with your printf of "(". Without an end of line, the stdout/console buffer won't get reliably flushed and it can create the illusion of a program being stuck.  I'm not certain if that's where you bug is. It's just a yellow flag of something I wouldn't do.

Looks quite okay when adding the pthread_joins: https://godbolt.org/z/vc1xe8v1r

At pthread_cond_signal(&cv), if at least one thread is locked in pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lk) else the next thread calling pthread_cond_wait(&cv,&lk) will be unblocked. Here there are 16 threads and one of them is unlocked and if the condition is not solved, the thread will loop and wait again**!**
Doing in place pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv), all pending threads are unlocked , some will loop but some others will exit their loop.
And pthread_join() is necessary, you must wait for thread's ends before terminating the main() function.

Please provide a [mre]. We shouldn't have to guess what your code looks like.
